# Why am I receiving an Overflow Error with my Array

Tags: arrays, vba

I have the following snippet of code that always fails when x=33. I can't for the life of me figure out why:

```vb
Sub doStuff()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim myArray(50) As Long

    For x = 0 To 50
        myArray(x) = 100000 + 1000 * x
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Do Debug.Print Ubound(myArray) and all will be revealed.

Comment: @freeflow That prints 50. What does that reveal?

Comment: It is a hole theory about some integers which do not fit into a byte, but in order to avoid such a situation, try cultivating your programming habit (in VBA) to forget about `Integer` variable and replace it with `Long`. In VBA it does not bring anything (good) regarding the way of memory loading. So, if you declare your variable `Dim x As Long` you will not have such a problem anymore. But not because x exceeded the maximum Integer range...

Comment: Sorry. Misread the question.

Comment: You gain nothing by using Integer instead of Long. Just stop using it altogether. It was useful to speed things up about 20-30 years ago.